# Cannot receive more than one message when using c++ sockets

Tags: c++, sockets

I have attached the code below, the title says it all. I am able to receive one message and then all other messages sent after the first don't get sent or arent read in.

Client, send_msg is called multiple times and cppClientSocket is the constructor that sets up the connection.

```
void cppClientSocket::send_msg(const char msg[], int size){
    sendto(sockfd ,msg, size , 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(serv));
}

cppClientSocket::cppClientSocket(int port){
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port = htons(port);
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
};
```

Server, cppServerSocket is used to construct the other side of the UDP socket. Retrieve is called continuously from another class (within a while loop).

```
cppServerSocket::cppServerSocket(int port){
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(fd<0){
        std::cout << "AN error occured when creating the socket" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    addrlen = sizeof(remaddr); /* length of addresses */ 

    /* bind the socket to any valid IP address and a specific port */ 
    memset((char *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr)); 
    //set to udp
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //host to network - long : convert a number into a 32-bit network representation.
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    //host to network - short : convert a number into a 16-bit network representation.
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed"); 
        return; 
    }
}

std::string cppServerSocket::retrieve(){
    int count = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE-1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen); 
    if(!displayedError && count < 0){
        std::cout << "An Error occured: " << strerror(errno) <<  std::endl;
        displayedError = true;
        return "";
    }
    if (count >= 0){
        printf("received message: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        std::string rcv(buf,count);
        return rcv;
    }
}
```

Appreciate the help!

UPDATE
If I modify the retrieve so that it acts like a server that will simply print every message it recieves, it works fine without error...

```
std::string cppServerSocket::retrieve(){
    for(;;){
    int count = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE-1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen); 
    if(!displayedError && count < 0){
        std::cout << "An Error occured: " << strerror(errno) <<  std::endl;
        displayedError = true;
        //return "";
    }else if (count >= 0){
        printf("received message: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        std::string rcv(buf,count);
        //return rcv;
    }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Below added the code that was used to call the original retrieve() method.

```
void check_socket(cppServerSocket css){
    string temp;

    temp.append(css.retrieve());
    if(temp.size()>0){
        std::cout << temp << std::endl; //for debugging
        debug.push_back(temp);
        debug.pop_front();
    }
}
```

Below is the code inside of main that calls the check_socket() method

```
    //code inside of main
    cppServerSocket css(3000);
    for(int i=0; i< test_time; i++){
        printScreen(test_devices, test_dev_status, false);
        t = clock();
        while(clock() - t < CLOCKS_PER_SEC){
            check_socket(css);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how `send_msg` is called? I suspect you receive everything, but received messages are null-terminated so `printf` prints only first of them stored in `buf`. If you are going to stick with `printf` debugging (which one should avoid) then you should print `count` value as well.

Comment: Consider checking the recvfrom output to diagnose further the problem. Upon successful completion, recvfrom() should return the length of the message in bytes. If no messages are available to be received should return 0. Otherwise, -1 and set errno to indicate the error.

Comment: @VTT I am calling it like so .... string msg("test"); send_msg(msg.c_str(), msg.size()). The printf in the retrieve function isn't really important to me I'm just using it to debug. My goal in that function is to return the string that was sent to the socket.

Comment: FYI, UDP allows 0-length messages, so `cppServerSocket::retrieve()` should be testing for `count >= 0` instead. Also, if `count == BUFSIZE` then `buf[count]` will be out of bounds if `buf` is `BUFSIZE` in size. You don't need to append a null terminator to `buf` at all if you pass `count` to `printf()` and the `string` constructor, eg: `printf("received message: \"%.*s\"\n", count, buf); std::string rcv(buf, count);`

Comment: @AdvSphere: "*If no messages are available to be received should return 0*" - that is not true. If the socket is blocking, it will block until a message is received. Otherwise it will fail with an `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` error. The only time that `recvfrom()` returns 0 is if either a 0-length message is received, or a connected socket is disconnected gracefully by the peer.

Comment: That's true, should had mentioned that.

Comment: Just have to add that for this case there's no connection, is UDP packets, so you shouldn't receive 0 from a disconnected peer. So for practical purposes of this question: recvfrom should return the length of the message in bytes or -1 an set errno to indicate the error.

Comment: @AdvSphere Looks like I am getting an error on my recvfrom. The error message I am getting is "Bad file descriptor"

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I passed BUFSIZE-1 to the recvfrom call and removed my line adding the null terminator (buf[count] = 0) without any luck. Still getting the bad file descriptor error.

Comment: @TylerWeiss: "bad file descriptor" means an invalid socket descriptor was passed to `recvfrom()`. Which means the problem is not in `receive()` itself, the caller has a logic bug that needs to be fixed

Comment: @AdvSphere: Like I said, UDP allows 0-length messages, so `count` very well could be 0 for valid messages. It depends on the actual protocol being implemented. Don't treat 0 as an error condition. In this particular case, it doesn't matter, since `return ""` and `return string(buf, 0);` would produce the same string value. For purposes of log reporting, a 0-length message is still a valid message. But the caller of `receive()` would not be able to differentiate between a 0-length message and a socket error , unless `cppServerSocket` stored that info somewhere.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added an update to my original post that should explain why my suspicion is with the retrieve method itself or the way I call the retrieve method. When  I added the infinite loop to the retrieve method the recvfrom never threw any errors and was able to receive all packets without error.

Comment: The problem is the bad file number. Nothing else. Possibly you are calling it with a closed socket for example. NB Both your constructor and your retrieve methods should throw exceptions when errors occur, rather than  allow the caller to continue without knowing they happened.

Comment: @EJP is it possible that the destructor for the cppServerSocket is getting called once the retrieve method has gone through once? Is it because I am not passing the cppServerSocket by reference? I do have the cppServerSocket close the socket in the destructor. So that would make sense.

Comment: Only you know what's in your own code. You should *certainly* be passing *any* object around by reference. Never by value. Otherwise you should have provided an explicit copy constructor to `dup()` the `fd`, but pass-by-reference is infinitely preferable: on performance grounds as well.

Answer (score 1):

GOT IT!!!

The problem was in check_socket(cppServerSocket css), because I was not passing by reference the descructor of my cppServerSocket was getting called, and in that destructor I had specified that the socket should close. So after the first message was recieved the socked would be closed. To fix this i passed cppServerSocket by reference

```
void check_socket(cppServerSocket &css){
    string temp;

    temp.append(css.retrieve());
    if(temp.size()>0){
        std::cout << temp << std::endl; //for debugging
        debug.push_back(temp);
        debug.pop_front();
    }
}
```

Thanks to all for the help!

Comment: I don't see the point of this method, actually. Just call your receive method.

Comment: The function appears to be keeping a history of past received messages, though it looks like it would only be allowed to keep 1 message at a time, unless other functions are also pushing into `debug`.

Comment: There is a lot more to this than what has been shown in this thread. The debug object is a deque of string objects initialized with 25 empty strings, so when one message comes in it pushes the oldest one out. and inserts the new message maintaining a size of 25.